# Parsing user input with some amount of escaped quotes

Tags: python

As a little challenge, I'm building a compiler in Python that takes in a file, in a language with syntax that I've made up, and runs it, executing my built-in functions like `println(somestr)`. (I understand the way I'm doing it is ill-advised and ugly).

This built-in function in particular is giving me some problems. I want to allow the user to have a line like this in their file:

```
println("John said " + "\"Foo.\"")
```

Which should output something like `John said "Foo."` Unfortunately, the way I read the file gives me something like this (with the `println` stripped):

```
"\"John said \" + \"\"Foo.\"\""
```

This makes it very difficult to tell apart the user-defined escapes from the auto-generated ones. That means I can't seperate the different strings, like this:

```
["John said ", "\"Foo\""]
```

So I can concatenate it. (It may also include variables, which I can handle.)

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get this far. I've tried using regular expressions through the `re` module, but I don't have much experience and couldn't get anything to work.

Is there a better way around it?

Comment: mix up your quotes ```("John said " + '"Foo."')```

Comment: @ilamaaa I personally would, but I'm not entering the data: possible users are

Comment: Don't really understand the problem then, you can escape with backslash, or you can wrap in different quotes. Using ```re``` is probably not the answer, but I am not sure of the issue so its hard to say.

Comment: Try looking up pthon's exec() command